# Equal frontend and backend links in application and one domain name

Tags: docker, nginx, url, architecture

I am trying to dockerize a new service written by our developers. It is Nginx & NodeJS on frontend and PHP & Laravel on backend.
These apps are in separate repos in Gitlab and it's implied that it will be two domain names - someting like *service.example.com* and *service-backend.example.com*.

When I asked why not to use one domain name they said that services have the same paths like

```
service.example.com/api/welcome/1
service-backend.example.com/api/welcome/1
```

and the only option to route is separate domains because paths could look even worse like

```
service.example.com/api/api/welcome/1
```

I suggested approach like [attempt to serve js/static pages first and if it fails, pass to PHP backend](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55891062/14399046) but the answer was that paths in all ends are working.

I don't like this multi-domain approach for one small service and I would like to have one entry point.

Is there best practices to architecture service URLs and service parts connection scheme?
Is it possible to serve equal URL paths on one domain name by nginx config?